# Order a list of lists based on a list - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a structure like this :

```
data = [[2,5,6,9,12,45,32] , [43,23,12,76,845,1] ,[65,23,1,54,22,123] , 
        [323,23,412,656,2,3] , [8,5,3,9,12,45,32] , [60,23,12,76,845,1] , 
        [5,23,1,54,22,123] , [35,2,12,56,22,34] ]
```

and I want  **order** this lists based on another list with the positions

```
order = [5,4,1,3,0,6,7, 2]
```

the result would be :

```
data_ordered = [[60,23,12,76,845,1],[8,5,3,9,12,45,32], [43,23,12,76,845,1], 
                [323,23,412,656,2,3] , [2,5,6,9,12,45,32] , [5,23,1,54,22,123] , 
                [35,2,12,56,22,34] ,[65,23,1,54,22,123] ]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data_ordered = [ data[i] for i in order]
```

Pretty basic list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
data_ordered = np.array(data)[np.array(order)].tolist()
```

And this will be done. Full example given below:

```
import numpy as np
data = [[2,5,6,9,12,45,32] , [43,23,12,76,845,1] ,[65,23,1,54,22,123] , 
        [323,23,412,656,2,3] , [8,5,3,9,12,45,32] , [60,23,12,76,845,1] , 
        [5,23,1,54,22,123] , [35,2,12,56,22,34] ]
order = [5,4,1,3,0,6,7, 2] 
data_ordered= np.array(data)[np.array(order)].tolist()
print(data_ordered)
```

Output is

```
[[60, 23, 12, 76, 845, 1], [8, 5, 3, 9, 12, 45, 32], [43, 23, 12, 76, 845, 1], [323, 23, 412, 656, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6, 9, 12, 45, 32], [5, 23, 1, 54, 22, 123], [35, 2, 12, 56, 22, 34], [65, 23, 1, 54, 22, 123]]
```

Use `numpy` to solve it.